# I keep getting the error "Use of unassigned variable" for "hit" for my raycast but I assign it. Here it is in the code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
Vector3 screenPoint = new Vector3(cam.pixelWidth / 2, cam.pixelHeight / 2, 0);
        Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(screenPoint);
        RaycastHit hit;
        GameObject hitObject = hit.transform.gameObject;
        PickUp target = hitObject.GetComponent<PickUp>();
```

i cant figure out why the code is breaking right there.

Comment: You _declared_ it, you did _not_ assign it a value. Assignment looks like this: `hit = someValue;`. The compiler is warning you that you haven't assigned a value to it, so calling `hit.transform.gameObject` would produce undefined results

Comment: The statement: `RaycastHit hit;` declares `hit` but it does not initialize it

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson not really undefined, more likely throw a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: `hit` does not have a value, it is never assigned. What is your expectation of the line `hit.transform.gameObject` when `hit` has no value?

Comment: figured it out i had the "GameObject hitObject = hit.transform.gameObject;" on the wrong line.

Comment: @Rafalon if the piece of memory used by `hit` is not explicitly initialized, it could contain valid-looking pointers. It would only throw a null reference if everything was set to zero

Answer (score 1):

That's because you try to access the `hit` variable before assigning a value to it:

```
Vector3 screenPoint = new Vector3(cam.pixelWidth / 2, cam.pixelHeight / 2, 0);
Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(screenPoint);
RaycastHit hit;

if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
    GameObject hitObject = hit.transform.gameObject;
    PickUp target = hitObject.GetComponent<PickUp>();
    // Perform actions with the target object
} else {
    // No object was hit by the raycast
}
```